# Kubernetes - cert-manager - Hashicorp Vault - Ready status of certificate is blank

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, cert-manager

I have created Clusterissuer that uses Vault and then issued certificate through it but the *Ready* status of the certificate is blank. There is nothing appearing in the events and cert-manager pod logs. It has not created a secret as well.

```
kubectl get cert
NAMESPACE             NAME                 READY                          SECRET                                             AGE
default               example-com                                         example-com                                      139m
```

clusterissuer.yaml

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: vault-clusterissuer
spec:
  vault:
    path: pki_int/sign/<role name>
    server: https://vault-cluster.example.com:8200
    caBundle: <base64 encoded cabundle pem>
    auth:
      appRole:
        path: approle
        roleId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
        secretRef:
          name: cert-manager-vault-approle
          key: secretId
```

The role name mentioned in the Path is the same as the role created in the Vault under pki_init.

certificate.yaml

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-com
spec:
  secretName: example-com 
  issuerRef:
    name: vault-clusterissuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: abc.example.com
  dnsNames:
  - abc.example.com
```

Since it is not generating any message or logs so I am not sure from where to start troubleshooting.

Does the value of *path* in clusterissuer.yaml looks right to you..?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is your secret cert-manager-vault-approle in the same namespace (default) as ClusterIssuer ? Also can you provide output of command: kubectl get clusterissuers -n default?

Comment: yes, both secret `cert-manager-vault-approle`  and ClusterIssuer are in the same namespace..

Comment: ```kubectl get secret,clusterissuers -n default | grep vault
secret/cert-manager-vault-approle         Opaque                                1      8m9s

clusterissuer.certmanager.k8s.io/vault-clusterissuer   7m6s```

Answer (score 2):

**CertificateConditionReady** indicates that a certificate is ready for use.

This is defined as:

- The target secret exists
- The target secret contains a certificate that has not expired
- The target secret contains a private key valid for the certificate
- The `commonName` and `dnsNames` attributes match those specified on the Certificate

I think the issue is in wrong `dnsNames` defined in `certificate.yaml` file:

Your certificate configuration file:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-com
spec:
  secretName: example-com 
  issuerRef:
    name: vault-clusterissuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: abc.example.com
  dnsNames:
  - abc.example.com
```

`dnsNames` field should have value: `www.abc.example.com` not `abc.example.com`

Final version should looks like:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-com
spec:
  secretName: example-com 
  issuerRef:
    name: vault-clusterissuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: abc.example.com
  dnsNames:
  - www.abc.example.com
```

Also remember that `path` field is the Vault role path of the PKI backend and *server* is the Vault server base URL. The `path` **MUST** USE the vault `sign` endpoint.

Please take a look: [issuer-vault-setup](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.8/tasks/issuers/setup-vault.html), [cert-clusterissuer](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/pull/1114/files).

Comment: The issue was with the cert-manager itself. The issue sorted after redeploying the cert-maanager from scratch.